# How to copy all iPhone voice memos to Mac locally?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, data-transfer, voice-memo

I have hundreds of voice memos on an iPhone. How do I transfer all of to my MacBook Air without relying on any cloud-based solution (due to privacy/security needs)?

PS: Older questions and answers talk about iTunes. Those do NOT apply in the year 2020 since iTunes is gone now and Apple recently redesigned how syncing with iDevices work.
PPS: I do not want to use iCloud for this.

Comment: Which macOS version are you using, which iOS version?

Comment: [iMazing](https://imazing.com) might be able to do this. AFAIK the demo version is free.

Comment: I assume that individually transferring each memo using AirDrop is not an option, right?

Comment: @nohillside That looks great, thank you! I would much prefer if that app was in the App Store but I will check it out and get it if the reputation is good.